# React : Appsync subscription doesn't work in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, graphql, subscription, aws-appsync

I'm writing a new app using react and aws-appsync and I can't make subscriptions work like I want.

I write a view, called by a router. It's a function tha uses states to store information.
To fetch data from my apis, I wrote the code into fuctions, called by useEffect hooks, so that they are executed only one time. This part i ok.

I need to subscibe to appsync API, and I tried to do it in different ways with no success :

When I call it directly from the function, the code is called 10,000 times. So I tried with hooks :

```
   async function subscribe() {
  API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onAddRunLab, { client_id: userid, lab_id: labid })
  ).subscribe({
      next: ({ provider, value }) => updateInfo(value.data.onAddRunLab),
      error: error => console.warn(error)
  });
  
useEffect(() => {
  // Create an scoped async function in the hook
  async function anyNameFunction() {
    await subscribe();
  anyNameFunction();
}, []);
```

But, It does not work using hooks. I think the subscription is done but after that the link between rect and API is lost and the updateInfo function is never called.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to make the subscription an async function instead do the following and make sure that you unsubscribe from the subscription.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(onAddRunLab, { client_id: userid, lab_id: labid })
  ).subscribe({
    next: ({ provider, value }) => updateInfo(value.data.onAddRunLab),
    error: (error) => console.warn(error),
  });
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks.
When will the unsuscribe be called ? Only once when leaving the page ?

Comment: It will be called once after the initial subscription is rendered and will perform a cleanup to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @Jonathan if this answers your question please upvote and approve it :)